# When not to Use Integration Tests

Tags: testing, tdd, integration-testing

I am writing an application that uses 3rd party libraries to instantiate and make some operations on virtualmachines.

At first I was writing integration tests to every functionality of the application. But them I found that these tests were not really helping since my environment had to be at a determined state, which turned the tests more and more difficult to write. And I decided to make only the unit and acceptance tests.

So, my question ... is/can there be method or a clue to notice when the integration tests are not to be used?? (or I am wrong and on all cases they should be written)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you don't plan on actually hooking your application up to anything "real"; no real containers, databases, resources or actual services. That's what an integration test is supposed to verify; that everything works properly together.

Answer (score 1):

Integration tests are good to test a full system that has well-defined inputs and outputs that are unlikely to change.  If your expected input/outputs change often then maintaining the test may become a maintenance challenge, or, worse, you may choose against improving an interface because of the amount of work that may be required to upgrade the integration tests.

Answer (score 1):

The easy and short rule is: Test in integration test what breaks **due to integration** and test the rest in unit tests **in isolation**.

You can even [hate integration tests](http://www.jbrains.ca/permalink/239). Writing a unit test for a function that takes only one integer parameter is hard enough. All possible combinations of state (internal and external(time, external systems)) and  input can make integration testing practically impossible (for a decent application.)